# Creating a custom list label in PowerPoint 2010 that uses A), B), etc

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I want to make a custom list in PowerPoint, where the labels are as follows (**desired format**):
A)
B)
C)
...

The nearest available options in PowerPoint that I can find are
**Capitals with a period instead of parentheses**
A.
B.
C.
...

or **lowercase rather than uppercase with parentheses**
a)
b)
c)
...
which are very close to what I want, but not exactly the same.

Is there any way I can get the desired format as shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The style A), B), C), ... seems to be hidden but it can be assigned by small trick. I wasn't able to assign the style using the user interface because style gallery looks to contain only limited presets. But I was able to get the style using VBA:

1. Have your presentation open and active (as current document) in PowerPoint
2. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to enter VBA (Visual Basic for Applications) environment
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to enter **Immediate** window
4. Paste the following command, adjust numbers and execute it by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> when your caret is at the end of the command:
   `ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Style = ppBulletAlphaUCParenRight`

   - the command is single-line, it appears to be wrapped only at this answer
   - in `Slides(1)` replace the number for your actual slide number (e.g. `Slides(36)`)
   - in `Shapes(1)` replace the number with order of your frame with bulleted list within all selectable objects on the slide (e.g. it can be `Shapes(5)`). If you are not sure, give it more attempts with different numbers.
5. Return back to PowerPoint by switching to its window and check the result.
6. If you succeed, you have the list A), B), C), ... as you requested. The key was in assigning of bullet style `ppBulletAlphaUCParenRight` which is not normally available in gallery. From now on, you can transfer this style to other slides using normal Copy and Paste.